# How to return a Task<string> using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, moq

I am using `XUnit` and `Moq` to test code from my logic layer. My logic layer also communicates with the data layer, so I want to mock the interface to keep my test simple.

I am wondering how I should return a `Task<string>` when I call the async Task method. My `GetOrder` method calls `GetOrderById` but the data layer method returns null.

**Edit:** I changed my unit test based on all the feedback. It works fine now.
**My test**:

```
public async void GetOrder()
{
    //Arrange 
    string expected = "test";
    
    var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    mock.Setup(arg => arg.GetOrderNameById(It.IsAny<int>())
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));
    var survey = new SurveyResult(mock.Object);

    //Act 
    string result = await survey.GetOrderNameById(It.IsAny<int>()));

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: FYI It is enough if you have `Assert.Equal(expected, result);` right after `string result = await survey.GetResult(score);` and you do not have to return a bool for unit testing

Comment: Your test doesn't show an `async void` usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Task.FromResult(expected)`

```
mock.Setup(arg => arg.GetScoreByTotalWeighting(value)).Returns(Task.FromResult(expected))
```

also I'd recomend to avoid `value` as parameter, when you dont care about that paramter when returning result. You can use `It.IsAny<int>()`, like that:

```
mock.Setup(arg => arg.GetScoreByTotalWeighting(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(expected))
```

Problem that you setting up `mock.Setup(arg =>  arg.GetScoreByTotalWeighting(value))` with `value == 0` and then call `survey.GetResult(score)` with `50`. Use `It.IsAny<int>()` at both places to avoid that problem, or pass same value:

`mock.Setup(arg => arg.GetScoreByTotalWeighting(score))`

Solution:

```
public async Task GetResult()
{
    //Arrange 
    string expected = "test";

    var mock = new Mock<IRetreiveQuestionRepository>();
    mock.Setup(arg => arg.GetScoreByTotalWeighting(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(expected);
    var survey = new SurveyResult(mock.Object);

    //Act 
    string result = await survey.GetResult(It.IsAny<int>());

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: I previously didn't know that ``It.IsAny<int>()``was a thing, this is very useful and exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the .ReturnsAsync method you're currently using, It's hard to tell why your subject is returning null without knowing the implementation. But I would double check the stubbing to see if you're specifying the value that is indeed passed to the real implementation or if you're missing any other stubbing for another method.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: I added my real implementation to clarify my question.